# How should someone with a cast on his right arm lean?

Tags: halacha, passover-seder-hagada

Bi'ur Halacha, OC 472:3, poses the following question: How does someone with a cast on his right arm lean at the Seder?

- On the one hand, he can only use his left arm to eat, so he should lean right.
- On the other hand, it's dangerous to lean right.

(He quotes the Shivlei Haleket who answers he should lean right, but he doesn't understand the Shivlei Haleket's rationale.)

The Bi'ur Halacha himself leaves the question open-ended. Does anyone else address this question?

Comment: Is this any different from a lefty?

Comment: @Double I assume the Biur Halacha’s issue arises from the fact that a lefty _can_ use his right hand, it’s just difficult, whereas if one’s right arm is in a cast (I assume he refers to an elbow cast) it’s not possible to use his right arm.

Comment: Note that one reason to lean to the left is because leaning to the right can cause the food to go down the wind pipe, causing choking. In order to cause the food to go down the esophagus a slight lean to the left would still allow you to use your left hand without actually resting on your left arm.